# Transpose multiple rows to single column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Can't figure out how to transpose multiple rows into a single column.

Current layout:

```
| a | b | c | d |
| e | f | g | h |
| i | j | k | l |
```

Desired layout:

```
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| e |
| f |
| g |
| h |
| i |
| j |
| k |
| l |
```

There are 214 rows, all with 4 columns, that I want to transpose into a single column. Starts from A2 and ends at D215.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FLATTEN()` function like-

```
=FLATTEN(A2:D)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, huge help. I was trying array formulas and transpose and nothing was working. Thanks.